# Two computers, same inputs, different results?

Tags: c++, debugging

I have two computers on which I do programming on, my home computer and my university computer. Both computers run visual c++ 2008 on 64-bit windows 7 home premium.

Why is it that even after clean rebuilds, in both debugging and release modes, the two computers give different results despite the identical code and inputs? The only real difference between the two computers is that one has better specs (core 2 quad vs core i7) but other than that there are no real differences.

Comment: You have a bug. Most likely either a race condition or stale pointer reference. If you show us some relevant code where you get inconsistent results, we may be able to help you.

Comment: To emphasize the above comment, we can't do anything without code. Anything.

Comment: What kind of program?  Is it something that does a lot of number crunching and/or floating point?

Comment: I'd guess that they aren't as identical as you imagine them to be.  Check your assumptions.

Comment: Your program might involve operations that depend on floating points, file system, environment, machine architecture, cpu temperature, system clock, available storage and so on... Only your code can reveal which one it is.

Comment: Another possible cause: using uninitialized memory. In this case the difference *might* go away when running with the debugger.

Comment: Hmm, I understand no code = no help, but I have still yet to narrow down the issue (or even understand it in my case). The program is essentially a number cruncher but it isn't mutithreaded though. Earlz, your probably right it might be a pointer issue.

Comment: As of right now, my coding is still quite crude and rudimentary so its likely a simpler problem with pointers (though that could be debated if it is in fact simple or not).

Comment: How different are the results? Do you know which result is correct? Do you have test data that should produce a specific output?

Comment: To rule out an overheating issue, or a problem with bad BIOS settings (such as RAM timings), you can try running a program called Prime95 on both computers. This is an intensive number-crunching program that stesses-out CPU and RAM to detect errors caused by overheating/overclocking. I think it's more likely that you have a bug in your program, so this suggestion is more of a last resort type of thing.

Comment: It is very difficult to explain how different the results are because the program outputs an enormous amount of data per run (around 7GB) but basically, the program analyses CAD geometries and determines clamping locations to hold a part during machining. One of the computers returns a zero clamp configuration for a particular machining step (which crashes the program) while the other computer produces valid results and continues. Currently that's the extent of my knowledge of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have problems with thread synchronization. It would be helpful if you provided more details. What does the code do? Maybe just show it.

If you repeat execution on Machine A, will it always yield the same output? And what happens if you spawn multiple processes on the same machine?

Comment: I'll get back to you in a few hours if two runs are identical...the program takes over an hour to run even with a small input data.